# JavaScript сравнение чисел в виде строки

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Сижу и пишу условие на Vue.js... Проверяю работоспособность и вижу, что не выполняется условие `'8.000000' < '2134124' (пример)` Как это возможно? Если убрать кавычки то всё хорошо, но значения (числа) с сервера (php) приходят в виде строки... Как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод "чистого" ЯваСкрипта [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). Он превратит строку в число с плавающей точкой.